# Alternative other than Node-Mailer to use in Contact Form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have a one page website that works with node.js, using this as web.js:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(port);
```

There is no routing.

I want to add a contact form. We don't have to use node-mailer for the job, if you have any better ideas I'd love to hear.

Comment: What are your actual requirements, and why doesn't node-mailer appeal to you?

Comment: The contact form will send a mail to a gmail account, using gmail with the following information:
Name, Phone number, mail, text.

Comment: Effectively dead now - https://nodemailer.com/status/

Comment: How is nodemailer dead now?  It's sponsered and has over 50+ contributors.  It's a very mature library currently with only 4 open issues and actively maintained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try  [Postmark.js](https://github.com/voodootikigod/postmark.js). It's simpler
Or [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs)

Comment: Thanks @Pradyumna Swain :)
So can you tell me an example of a contact form which  will send a mail to a gmail account with the following information: Name, Phone number, mail, text ??

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/postmark or http://www.xiandg.com/3925427/codep1/how-to-use-postmark-email-on-nodejs

Comment: I try the postmark but the confirmation email is bouncing again and again how I can resolve that issue?

Comment: @AdilIjaz bouncing emails is nothing related to the library to write the email. it's most likely your mail provider that is causing problems or misconfigured